# WPF Visiblity Binding to Boolean Expression with multiple Variables

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two Booleans I want to show Image based on their value, something like this :

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Image Visibility="{Binding (Boolean1 && Boolean2),Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Notice Boolean1 and Boolean2 expression.

Comment: binding path doesnt support this kind of expressions, make a `get`-only property in a view model `public bool Boolean3 { get { return Boolean1 && Boolean2; }}` and bind to Boolean3

Comment: there must be a B̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶  easy way to do something like that inline ?

Comment: You need to use a multibinding and a multivaluevonverter http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/12/wpf-multibinding-example.html#.WKrPW_LNjMM

Comment: Either use an IMultiValueConverter or an Style with a MultiDataTrigger as per my answer.

Comment: @Slacker actually allowing you to code directly into the view would break the entire MVVM concept, appearance and function must be seperated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no `&&` operator defined in XAML but you could bind to several properties and use an `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourMultiConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Boolean1" />
            <Binding Path="Boolean2" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Visibility>
</Image>
```

---

```
public class YourMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool a = (bool)values[0];
        bool b = (bool)values[1];

        return a && b ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Or you could use an `Image` style with conditions:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Boolean1}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Boolean2}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Sorry silly question how to define ({StaticResource YourMultiConverter}) ?

Comment: @Stacker same way you define any converter create it as a static resource in relevant resource dictionary, just remember you need to define the namespace if you haven't already

Comment: <local:YourMultiValueConverter  x:Key="YourMultiValueConverter "/> in <Window.Resources>.

Comment: You should return `null` in ConvertBack because:
"The data binding engine does not catch exceptions that are thrown by a user-supplied converter. Any exception that is thrown by the ConvertBack method or any uncaught exceptions that are thrown by methods that the ConvertBack method calls are treated as run-time errors. Handle anticipated problems by returning null."

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 5):

mm8 has provided the correct answer however a slight improvement would be this

```cs
public class LogicalAndConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public IValueConverter FinalConverter{get;set;}

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool rtn = values.All(v=>(bool)v);

        if(FinalConverter==null)    
            return rtn;
        else
            return FinalConverter.Convert(rtn,targetType,parameter,culture);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

this then allows you do use different converters with out rewriting the multiconverter

```
<local:LogicalAndConverter x:Key="LogicalAndConverter ">
    <local:LogicalAndConverter.FinalConverter>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
    </local:LogicalAndConverter.FinalConverter>
</local:LogicalAndConverter>
```

Comment: This is a waaay to much underrated answer. Really smooth converter piping.

Comment: I like this answer because of the flexibility!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind adding another package to your project, DevExpress' MVVM framework (which is freely available), has a binding markup extension called [DXBinding](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/115771/mvvm-framework/dxbinding/dxbinding) that allows one to write binding functions / expressions.

```xml
<Image Visibility="{DXBinding 'Boolean1 and Boolean2', Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multivalue converter to resolve this issue

XAML :

```
 <TextBlock Name="textBlockOutput" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                <Binding Path="TextOne" />
                <Binding Path="TextTwo" />
                <Binding Path="TextThree" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>




 public class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string one = values[0] as string;
        string two = values[1] as string;
        string three = values[2] as string;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(one) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(two) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(three))
        {
            return one + two + three;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: while your answer is correct a better explanation of why this fixes it would improve this as an answer