# wpf specify multiple DataBindings in Groupbox IsEnabled Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a GroupBox whose IsEnabled Property is set via a property on the ViewModel as under:-

```
<GroupBox>
    <Canvas IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentRec.Current_Selected_Category.NoBonus,Converter={StaticResource TFC}}">
        <Label Content="Amount:" Width="55" Canvas.Left="9" Canvas.Top="-2"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBonusAmount" Width="76"  Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="20" Text="Some text"/>
        <Label Content="Bonus:" Canvas.Top="38" Width="54" Canvas.Left="10"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBonus" Width="76"  Canvas.Left="13" Canvas.Top="58" Text="Some Text"/>
    </Canvas>
<Groupbox>
```

There are more than one properties in my viewmodel affecting the IsEnabled property of Canvas.How do i specify those additional properties against the IsEnabled property of Canvas?

Comment: Use a MultiBinding with a converter.

Comment: Use a multi value converter, like the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42343062/109702).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `MultiBinding` with a converter:

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Resources>
        <local:MultiConverter x:Key="conv" />
    </GroupBox.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.IsEnabled>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                <Binding Path="CurrentRec.Current_Selected_Category.NoBonus" />
                <Binding Path="TheOtherProperty" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Canvas.IsEnabled>
        <Label Content="Amount:" Width="55" Canvas.Left="9" Canvas.Top="-2"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBonusAmount" Width="76"  Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="20" Text="Some text"/>
        <Label Content="Bonus:" Canvas.Top="38" Width="54" Canvas.Left="10"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBonus" Width="76"  Canvas.Left="13" Canvas.Top="58" Text="Some Text"/>
    </Canvas>
</GroupBox>
```

The converter class should implement the [IMultiValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and return a `bool` from the `Convert` method:

```
public class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool noBonus = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[0]);
        bool theOtherSourceProperty = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[1]);

        //..

        return noBonus && theOtherSourceProperty;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```